# How to share record in CRM 365

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I want to share my record when several condition is fulfilled, can I do that with plugin? I have request transfer record I want to share, so when request transfer status is submited I will share the record to user that I get from warehouse in my request transfer field. Can I do that with plugin?

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
  if(context.MessageName.ToUpper() == "UPDATE")
  {
    int requestStatus = transferImage.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("mjt_request_status").Value;
    if(requestStatus == 2)
    {
      EntityReference warehouse = transferImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("mjt_request_to ");

      ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
      var warehouses = service.Retrieve("msdyn_warehouse ", warehouse.Id, columnSet);

      if (warehouses.Attributes.ContainsKey("mjt_administrator"))
      {
        adminstrator = warehouses.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("mjt_administrator");
      }

      if(adminstrator != null)
      {
      }

    }
  }
}
```

My code is just ended where I get the adminstrator from transfer request, and then I have no idea how to share the request to my user.

Comment: You're missing an "i" in `administrator` :)

Comment: also you're not declaring your `administrator` variable (`var administrator...`) but this might be a copy & paste error

Comment: And some of your `GetAttributeValue` methods have spaces in the string. This will result in a `null` value

Comment: yes thanks for your correction , its already work. i was in rush because of deadline lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `GrantAccessRequest` to do this.

```
// Grant the user read access to the record.
var grantAccessRequest1 = new GrantAccessRequest
{
    PrincipalAccess = new PrincipalAccess
    {
        AccessMask = AccessRights.ReadAccess,
        Principal = adminstrator
    },
    Target = transferReference
};

serviceProxy.Execute(grantAccessRequest1);
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/sample-share-records-using-grantaccess-modifyaccess-revokeaccess-messages)